# how to add hover effect in hightcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

can we add hover effect in hightcharts (donut chart) ..Can we add hover effect in donut chart shown in given url

http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html

please check above link and hover any slice .it dark the selected slice and grey out the other as same effect in legend

can we do in highcharts

here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/sk0603wj/

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   10.38],
                ['IE',       56.33],
                ['Chrome', 24.03],
                ['Safari',    4.77],
                ['Opera',     0.91],
                {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.2,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it is not very straight forward. Here you can see the building blocks of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ehrgge7/2/

1) you need to to remember the reference to the chart

```
var hc = Highcharts.chart(...
```

2) Then you can use mouseOver and mouseOut events on the elements to modify the points of the series. Here is an example of mouse over event, that for all but hovered item updates the color to something.

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point:{
            events:{
                mouseOver:function(ev){ 
                  hc.series[0].points.forEach(
                      function(i){
                          if(ev.target !== i ){
                              i.update({color:'rgba(150,100,50,0.1)'});
                          }
                      }
                  )
              }
            }
          },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    halo: {
                        size: 9,
                        opacity: 0.75
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3) To make the desired effect, you have to have a table of colors that you will be assigning to your points.

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

var hc = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 40
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point:{
            events:{
                mouseOver:function(ev){ 
                  hc.series[0].points.forEach(
                  function(i){
                        if(ev.target !== i ){
                        if(i.color.indexOf('rgba') < 0) {
                        i.update({color: convertHex(i.color) + ",0.1)"});
                       }else{
                         i.update({color: i.color.replace('1)', '0.1)')});
                       }
                        }
                     }
                  )
              },
              mouseOut:function(ev){
                 hc.series[0].points.forEach(
                  function(i){
                    i.update({color: i.color.replace('0.1','1')});

                     }
                  )
              }
            }
          },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    halo: {
                        size: 9,
                                                    opacity: 0.75
                    }
                }
            },

            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -50,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '75%']
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        innerSize: '50%',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   10.38],
            ['IE',       56.33],
            ['Chrome', 24.03],
            ['Safari',    4.77],
            ['Opera',     0.91],
            {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        ],
        color: ['rgba(12,181,236,1)', 'rgba(247,181,236,1)', 'rgba(128,133,233,1)', 'rgba(241,92,128,1)', 'rgba(241,181,236,1)', 'rgba(247,181,236,1)']
    }]
});

function convertHex(hex){
  hex = hex.replace('#','');
  r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16);
  g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16);
  b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16);

  result = 'rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+'';
  return result;
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ehrgge7/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of what you wanted to achieve in pure JavaScript using only Highcharts library.

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
   events: {
     load () {
       colorAllGray.call(this)
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver(e) {
            colorAllGray.call(chart)
            e.target.update({
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[e.target.index]
            })
          },
          mouseOut() {
            colorAllGray.call(chart)
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    innerSize: '50%',
    data: [
      ['Firefox', 10.38],
      ['IE', 56.33],
      ['Chrome', 24.03],
      ['Safari', 4.77],
      ['Opera', 0.91], {
        name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
        y: 0.2,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
})

function colorAllGray() {
  this.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
    point.update({
      color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.1)'
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500"></div>
```

Live example
https://jsfiddle.net/5eq6vx3f/